# Sending Object from SOAP Handler to Web Service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

How can I send an Object from a SOAP Handler to the web service?  I know I can modify the SOAP message but I'm trying to send the whole SOAP message back.  In the web service I don't have access to the SOAP envelope.  Also, this is implementing a wsdl and I can't change the parameter type which is a particular kind of XML.  So I'm thinking of using some kind of parallel messaging mechanism between the SOAP Handler and the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SOAP Handler,

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext mc) {
...
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
SOAPMessage soapMsg = mc.getMessage();

mc.put("soapMsg", out); 
mc.setScope("soapMsg", MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);  
...
}
```

In the Web Service:

```
MessageContext messageCtx = context.getMessageContext();
String doc = (messageCtx.get("soapMsg")).toString();
```

Comment: Where is context defined in the Web Service?